# is there any api which downloads image from google images in java and how to use it

Tags: java

Is there any API which downloads image from Google images in java and how to use it.

I used https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=boy&rsz=8 but it doesn't give more than 2 result and I want to show all result in `JDesktopPane` I tried this.
thanks in advance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=boy&rsz=8");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

            String line;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            System.out.println(builder.toString());
           // for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
           // {

              JSONArray js = json.getJSONObject("responseData").getJSONArray("results");
              for(int j=0;j<js.length();j++)
              {




           //   }




              JSONObject  json1 = js.getJSONObject(j);
              String imageUrl=json1.getString("url");
           // String imageUrl = json.getJSONObject("responseData").getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(i).getString("url");

               BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageUrl));

            // for downloading the image
            // connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070723 Iceweasel/2.0.0.6 (Debian-2.0.0.6-0etch1)");

            File  outputfile = new File("D:\\saved"+j+".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
            System.out.println("downloded"+j);
            }
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Failure", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe that the API has being deprecated, check [here](https://developers.google.com/image-search/) for details

Comment: is there any other open source Api except Google which can used image downloading in java in desktop application.